# Remote OS Command Injection - scanned by ZAP

Tags: web-application, zap

A web scan by ZAP indicated that my website is vulnerable to a Remote OS command injection. Details are below:

This is the URL the scanner found vulnerable:

```
https://[redacted]/[redacted]?address=ZAP%22%26sleep+15%26%22&email=foo-bar%40example.com&message=&name=ZAP&phone=9999999999
```

This is the exploit:

```
ZAP"&sleep 15&"
```

Is this considered a true exploit or just a false positive?

Comment: What happens when you visit the url?

Comment: Nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case every time I see this vulnerability it is false positive, this command is "sleep", so if the response long, and takes approximately 15 seconds, which can happen for various reasons (network problems, VPN problems) OWASP ZAP return this as vulnerability.

You should run this request several times and see if every response takes approximately 15 seconds, if not, I would classify this as false positive.

Comment: According to my reading of the source code for this part of the scanner at https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/ascanrules/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrules/CommandInjectionScanRule.java , the vulnerability will be found **even if the web page simply returns the "command string" back in the HTML**. This will obviously cause a huge number of false positives, as it in no way proves that the command was actually executed by the OS.